# Python - Iterative searchtree implementation

Tags: python, iteration, limit

I am trying to implement an iterative function, which searches a given search-tree for an integer, and reports back whether that integer exist within the search-tree.
So far it works for returning True if the value exists, but runs into a "list index out of range" error when searching for values not existant within the search-tree.

```
    return [l,v,r]

def left(l) :
    return l[0]

def right(l) :
    return l[2]

def value(l) :
    return l[1]

def empty() :
    return []



def iterative_check_for_elem(val,tree):
    while not tree == False:
        if val == value(tree):
            return True
            break
        elif val < value(tree):
            tree = left(tree)
        elif val > value(tree):
            tree = right(tree)
    return False



test_tree = node(node(node(empty(),30,empty()),40,node(empty(),45,empty())),50,node(node(empty(),55,empty()),60,node(empty(),70,empty())))

print(iterative_check_for_elem(45,test_tree))
```

45 works in the call to print, 47 runs into the error.
I can not figure out what is going wrong honestly.

Comment: post full code.

Comment: can't reproduce the issue, code is incomplete

Comment: Have figured it out, just changed the double negation „while not tree = False“ to „while tree“

Answer (score 0):

Your tree has a bunch of empty nodes in it (created by `empty()`), and your search code doesn't deal with them properly. While an empty list is falsey, it's not equal to `False`, which your code seems to expect. Try rewriting the loop condition as:

```
while tree:
    ...
```

Or you could be more explicit and do a check like:

```
while len(tree) > 0:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed „while not tree = False“ to „while tree“ and that worked. „While x“ is just very unintuitive for someone with no coding experience.

Comment: Whoops, I did incorrectly simplify the double-negative in the original code. If you find the "interpret a list as a truth value" part as too confusing, try the option with `len` I gave at the end, it's more explicit what it cares about. You might also try using a different kind of object for the "missing" nodes of the tree, like `None` (then you could loop with `while tree is not None`, which is pretty clear).